# load bitmap file in python and convert it to HBITMAP

Tags: python, python-2.7, winapi

I trying to access some DLL functions using ctypes in Python. One of the functions requires a bitmap file as input, and the format of this bitmap input should be HBITMAP. I can load a bitmap file into the workspace e.g. using PIL.Image.OPEN, but how do I convert this to HBITMAP?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with the Windows API then I would be consistent, so use [`LoadBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or [`LoadIimage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) instead of PIL to load an image, that will give you a valid `HBITMAP` (<del>which is just a long number or `DWORD`</del>) which you can work with.

If you still want to use PIL for reading the image, then use [`CreateBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Hope it helps!

Comment: @eryksun You're right! I'm surprised, I never use a handle as a pointer, just as a numeric identifier to a specific object. Thanks for the data.